# Hide add to cart button when First Variation Is selected from drop down shopiy

Tags: shopify, hide

When User select first option from the product variations, hide the add to cart and PayPal buttons otherwise show both buttons.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("select.single-option-selector").change(function(){
          var first = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
          var second = $('option:eq(0)').val();
     if (first == second){
           $("#addToCart-product-template").hide();
           $(".shopify-payment-button__button").hide();
  }
  else{

           $("#addToCart-product-template").show();
           $(".shopify-payment-button__button").show();
  }

      });
  });
```

Comment: Is this a questions or an answer? It's not very clear what you are looking for if you are looking for something at all.

Comment: the above code works better just replace the id and classes with the id and classes of your specific button

Comment: My own code is working now